# Infinite setStatus() loop when requesting a JSF page

Tags: jsf-2, tomcat7

Hi i've upgraded my configs and libs to hibernate 4 spring 3.1.1 richfaces 4 ....
And i'm running on tomcat 7.
But when i try to open my index-page the Server runs a loop.
And when i try to set a breakpoint in "ViewHandlerResponseWrapper" eclipse stucks and i cant debug it to find a reason. And the source for "HttpServletResponseWrapper" seems not to be available. The exception of the loop looks like this:

```
    Apr 05, 2012 9:21:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
    Schwerwiegend: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.setStatus(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:201)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.setStatus(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:201)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerResponseWrapper.setStatus(ViewHandlerResponseWrapper.java:88)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.setStatus(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:201)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.setStatus(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:201)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerResponseWrapper.setStatus(ViewHandlerResponseWrapper.java:88)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.setStatus(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:201)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.setStatus(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:201)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerResponseWrapper.setStatus(ViewHandlerResponseWrapper.java:88)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.setStatus(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:201)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.setStatus(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:201)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerResponseWrapper.setStatus(ViewHandlerResponseWrapper.java:88)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.setStatus(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:201)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.setStatus(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:201)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerResponseWrapper.setStatus(ViewHandlerResponseWrapper.java:88)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.setStatus(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:201)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.setStatus(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:201)
... and so on
```

hope somebody can help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok found it by myselfe:
i had to upgrade the header of my faces-config.xml from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE faces-config PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JavaServer Faces Config 1.1//EN"
                              "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-facesconfig_1_1.dtd">
<faces-config>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
```