# RESTful service using Spark web framework on Tomcat

Tags: java, rest, java-8, tomcat8, spark-java

I want to create a restful api in Java 8 using Spark web framework version 2.6.0, JSF 2.2, Jstl 1.2 and I want to deploy it on Tomcat server 8.5.9. I have this configuration in my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <filter>        
        <filter-name>SparkFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>spark.servlet.SparkFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>applicationClass</param-name>
            <param-value>ec.apicorreo.filtro.InicioSpark</param-value>            
        </init-param>       
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>         
        <filter-name>SparkFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
...
...
 </web-app>
```

But I have this exception: 
`javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception.`
And the root cause: `java.lang.StackOverflowError
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.setStatus(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:201)
    com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerResponseWrapper.setStatus(ViewHandlerResponseWrapper.java:88).`
I don´t know what I am missing.

Comment: Looks like `setStatus` is a recursive method. Otherwise, something is getting called in a circle

Comment: I don't handle that, I only have this filter:public class InicioSpark implements SparkApplication {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        get("/hello", (req, res) -> "Hola mundo!");
        
    }
}

Comment: this seems to be a faces issue

Comment: have you the index.xhtml file? maybe this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024312/infinite-setstatus-loop-when-requesting-a-jsf-page

Comment: Do you need faces? I don't think Spark or tomcat does

Comment: I have a index.xhtml but I don't use faces-config @RamiresMoreira.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to remove JSF and the problem was solved and I'm going to use views
and templates from spark http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#views-and-templates